# Should one redact PII from spam?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flags

In clear cases of bot/spam posts such as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416235/what-does-it-take-to-save-a-life-stand-by-me-i-will-survive), when the original posting includes what appears to be personally identifiable information (in this case, a name and postal address), is it good form to redact the supposed PII while awaiting the post being marked for deletion by a sufficiently-privileged moderator (as I, in this case have)?

Comment: Editing a post invalidates existing spam flags on it, so better not.

Comment: @muru I don't think that's true actually. It didn't happen in this specific case, anyway. The timeline shows 3 spam flags, then DopeGhoti's edit and then another 3 flags and the post was deleted. So the edit didn't invalidate the 1st 3 flags.

Comment: @terdon ah, yes. It's rolling back that affects spam flags, not editing. "Rolling back a post to a previous state will revert to the number of flags from that particular revision." https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/270345 My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as it is not personally identifying information: it is just part of the scam.

Flag it for deletion.

Comment: I did indeed mark for moderator attention and it was ultimately deleted.  However, while I was confident that the name and postal address was not the _poster's_ PII, it looked reasonable to presume it might be _somebody's_ PII, which is why I took the additional step of redacting.  Are you saying that I should not have done so?

Comment: I wouldn't have bothered. It's a scam; the only victims are people stupid enough to buy it.